# Showing Database values in the table in asp

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I want to show the Database Values in a table in asp.net.
The below code is a simple query:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = new SqlConnection("");
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customers ORDER BY CustomerID";
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Connection.Close();
        }
```

How can the table demonstrate DB Values? (Code needed)

Comment: RTFM: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx a datagrid is one control you can use to quickly display data, another is a gridview.  Most of the stuff in ASP.net through webforms makes it pretty easy to do it without writing a loop and outputting HTML, I'd try to stick with those while learning.'

Comment: Repeater is another option - it might be easier to comprehend for asp.net newbie.

Comment: Can you try as you mention by Snowburnt and then post the code which you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You have several missing pieces in your code such as missing connection string, not relating the command to the connection and using ExecuteNonquery.

This is a good example of what you want to do: [MSDN-DataGridView DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). While the example is not for Windows Forms, the same code for data access in the method GetData still applies.

in your application you could use the filled table (from the example) as in:

```
MyDataGrid.DataSource = GetData("Select * from Customer")
MyDataGrid.DataBind();
```

Alternatively, You can also use Visual Studio environment to connect your data grid view to the DataSource without writing code.

The above is just a simple example there are different better ways to do the same thing. However, this is a start.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned in the comments, you need a DataList, Gridview or Repeater on your page to bind to this data. Without it you're connecting but not displaying what you get.

The easiest thing to do would be drop a Gridview on the page and set its datasource to your command object. You need to define a CommandType on the command, too, or you'll probably throw an error.

```
GridView1.DataSource = cmd;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

You're also missing a Try...Catch...Finally with the Close() call in the Finally block. If you don't do that you could wind up with zombie connections that'll trash performance in your database.